Interpretation function not working properly with Graphics
The Interpretation function does not seem to be working properly with Graphics on my computer (MacOS 14.2.1, Mathematica 14.0.0.0). Instead of returning what it should be interpreted as, it returns what it is only supposed to display. Am I misunderstanding something? Does anyone has the same issue?
What it is supposed to do (from the documentation):

What it actually does:


You are very likely copying the wrong thing. Do not click on the black circle and copy it, because this will indeed copy just the Graphics expression. Instead, select the whole expression with mouse (ie. the whole black circle, so that it gets blue background), and copy this instead. This should then work as expected.


That is indeed what was going on. Thank you!

Also works as documented with v14.0.0 and macOS  14.4 .1
